# Spark colocated join between two partitioned dataframes

Tags: scala, join, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

For the following join between two `DataFrames` in Spark 1.6.0

```
val df0Rep = df0.repartition(32, col("a")).cache
val df1Rep = df1.repartition(32, col("a")).cache
val dfJoin = df0Rep.join(df1Rep, "a")
println(dfJoin.count)
```

Does this join not only co-partitioned but also co-located? I know that for RDDs if using the same partitioner and shuffled in the same operation, the join would be co-located. But what about dataframes? Thank you.

Comment: According to these two sources, Co-location of two RDDs is guaranteed in this case. https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/spark-users/gUyCSoFo5RI https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/high-performance-spark/9781491943199/ch04.html

Comment: I think both of those links are to discussions about RDDs. It's not clear if you can assure partitions are co-located in the same way for Dataframes/DataSets. I am interested in a more definative answer.

Answer (score 1):

[https://medium.com/@achilleus/https-medium-com-joins-in-apache-spark-part-3-1d40c1e51e1c]

According to the article link provided above Sort-Merge join is the default join, would like to add important point

> For Ideal performance of Sort-Merge join, it is important that all
>   rows having the same value for the join key are available in the same
>   partition. This warrants for the infamous partition exchange(shuffle)
>   between executors. Collocated partitions can avoid unnecessary data
>   shuffle. Data needs to be evenly distributed n the join keys. The
>   number of join keys is unique enough so that they can be equally
>   distributed across the cluster to achieve the max parallelism from the
>   available partitions