# What is the difference between bucketBy and partitionBy in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hdfs, partitioning

For example, I want to save a table, what is the difference between the two strategies?

#### bucketBy:

```
someDF.write.format("parquet")
      .bucketBy(4, "country")
      .mode(SaveMode.OverWrite)
      .saveAsTable("someTable")
```

#### partitionBy:

```
someDF.write.format("parquet")
      .partitionBy("country") # <-- here is the only difference
      .mode(SaveMode.OverWrite)
      .saveAsTable("someTable")
```

I guess, that bucketBy in first case creates 4 directories with countries, while partitionBy will create as many directories as many unique values in column "countries". is it correct understanding ?

Comment: This is already answered. I hope this link helps. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/19131221/7022089](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19131221/7022089)

Answer (score 7):

Some differences:

- `bucketBy` is only [applicable for file-based data sources in combination with DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable.html) i.e. when saving to a Spark managed table, whereas `partitionBy` can be used when writing any file-based data sources.
- `bucketBy` is intended for the write once, read many times scenario, where the up-front cost of creating a persistent bucketised version of a data source pays off by [avoiding a costly shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61758185/1859370) on read in later jobs. Whereas `partitionBy` is useful to meet the data layout requirements of downstream consumers of the output of a Spark job.

> I guess, that bucketBy in first case creates 4 directories with countries, while partitionBy will create as many directories as many unique values in column "countries". is it correct understanding?

Yes, for `partitionBy`. However `bucketBy` will create 4 bucket files (Parquet by default).

Answer (score 0):

Unlike bucketing in Apache Hive, Spark SQL creates the bucket files per the number of buckets and partitions. In other words, the number of bucketing files is the number of buckets multiplied by the number of task writers (one per partition).

You could also use bucketBy along with [partitionBy](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.html#partitionBy-java.lang.String...-), by which each partition (last level partition in case of multilevel paritioning) will have 'n' number of buckets.